# Unable to get at attachment from url

Tags: json, lotus-domino

I need to get at an attachment stored in a Lotus Notes Document, using a url.

I can get the document, ok but when I try the url to get the attachment, I get a 404 Attachment not found.

Tried using the examples in the Domino Data Service guide

http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/domino/8.5.3/doc/designer_up1/en_us/DominoDataService.html

The url to get the document is

https://mym.dev-imaginovation.net/Applications/Correspondence/corr2017.nsf/api/data/documents/unid/FB1620DDCA1D8C538025836000401312

This produces the json and from here I can see the attachment name (shown below)

```
  "boundary":"--0__=8FBB096ADFDA03268f9e8a93df938690918c8FBB096ADFDA0326"
          },
                    {
            "contentType":"application\/octet-stream; name=\"081409362-E_Notif_GoThrough_Regist.PDF\"",
            "contentID":"<2__=8FBB096ADFDA03268f9e8a93df93869091@local>",
            "contentDisposition":"attachment; filename=\"081409362-E_Notif_GoThrough_Regist.PDF\"",
            "contentTransferEncoding":"base64",
            "data":"JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iaiA8PC9EZWNvZGVQYXJtczw8L0sgLTEvQ29sdW1ucyAyN
```

when I try the url

https://mym.dev-imaginovation.net/Applications/Correspondence/corr2017.nsf/api/data/documents/unid/FB1620DDCA1D8C538025836000401312/$File/081409362-E_Notif_GoThrough_Regist.PDF

I get a web page

{
    "code":404,
    "text":"Not Found",
    "message":"Attachment not found"
}

Any ideas?

(The links do not work as the dev site is not accessible from the www)

Thanks

Graeme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is already in the response to the GET document request:

```
{
    "contentType":"application\/octet-stream; name=\"081409362-E_Notif_GoThrough_Regist.PDF\"",
    "contentID":"<2__=8FBB096ADFDA03268f9e8a93df93869091@local>",
    "contentDisposition":"attachment; filename=\"081409362-E_Notif_GoThrough_Regist.PDF\"",
    "contentTransferEncoding":"base64",
    "data":"JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iaiA8PC9EZWNvZGVQYXJtczw8L0sgLTEvQ29sdW1ucyAyN ..."
}
```

The `data` property contains the base64-encoded content of the attachment. The `contentTransferEncoding` property tells you how it is encoded.

Depending on what version of Domino you are using, you can also change the GET document request to get an attachment link instead of the attachment content. Just add `?attachmentlinks=true` to the end of the request URL. That will cause the response to have a `contentLocation` property -- the value of which is the relative URL of the attachment data.

**Important:** The `attachmentlinks` parameter was added in Domino 9.0.1 FP9. If you are using an older version of Domino, `?attachmentlinks=true` is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The '$file' URL path isn't an 'api/data' path, but you an use the unid and filename to build an alternative path (assuming you just want the attachment the old fashioned way on any Domino server):

> https://mym.dev-imaginovation.net/Applications/Correspondence/corr2017.nsf/0/FB1620DDCA1D8C538025836000401312/$File/081409362-E_Notif_GoThrough_Regist.PDF

Or more generally:

```
domain/app-path/db.nsf/view/key/$file/filename
domain/app-path/db.nsf/view/unid/$file/filename
```

Or using '0' for view-name placeholder:

> domain/app-path/db.nsf/0/unid/$file/filename